# Create graph having nodes with no labels and no separations between its edges with Graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I want to generate this kind of graphs with graphviz :

[image]

I tried the following code :

```
graph{
    node [shape=none label=""]
    1 [pos="0,0!"]
    2 [pos="1.2145,0.694!"]
    3 [pos="1.2145,2.082!"]
    4 [pos="0.0,2.776!"]
    5 [pos="-1.2145,2.082!"]
    6 [pos="-1.2145,0.694!"]

    1 -- 2
    2 -- 3
    3 -- 4
    4 -- 5
    5 -- 6
    6 -- 1
}
```

But I get the following output

[image]

Is it possible to make nodes without labels and edges without any separation between than ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you are trying to create a hexagon-shaped node, do this: mynode[shape=hexagon] (see https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html)  Or are you trying to create custom-shaped nodes?

Comment: I want to create graphs made by hexagons put end to end, and I need to specify each node's coordinates. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
digraph D {
  graph [nodesep=.02]
  node [shape=hexagon] 
  A B C
  }
```

Gives this:
[image]

And this:

```
digraph D {
  graph [nodesep=.02]
  node [shape=hexagon orientation=30] 
  A B C
  }
```

Gives this:

[image]